# What does the parameters in scipy.stats.zipf mean?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, confidence-interval, zipf

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zipf.html#scipy.stats.zipf)

> The probability mass function for zipf is:
>
> zipf.pmf(k, a) = 1/(zeta(a) * k**a)
> for k >= 1.
>
> zipf takes `a` as shape parameter.
>
> The probability mass function above is defined in the “standardized” form. To shift distribution use the loc parameter. Specifically, zipf.pmf(k, a, loc) is identically equivalent to zipf.pmf(k - loc, a).

**But what does the `a` and `k` refer to? What does "shape parameter" mean?**

Additionally, in `scipy.stats.zipf.interval`, there's an `alpha` parameter.

The description of the `.interval()` method is simply:

> Endpoints of the range that contains alpha percent of the distribution

**What does the `alpha` parameter mean?** Is that the "confidence interval"?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269255/is-it-right-to-use-normal-distribution-to-compute-confidence-intervals-of-a-poin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **What does "shape parameter" mean?**

As the name suggests, a shape parameter determines the shape of a distribution. This is probably easiest to explain when starting with what a shape parameter is *not*:

1. A *location* parameter shifts the distribution but leaves it otherwise unchanged. For example, the mean of a normal distribution is a location parameter. If `X` is normally distributed with mean `mu`, then `X + a` is normally distributed with mean `mu + a`.
2. A *scale* parameter makes the distribution wider or narrower. For example, the standard deviation of a normal distribution is a scale parameter. If `X` is normally distributed with standard deviation `sigma`, then `X * a` is normally distributed with standard deviation `sigma * a`.
3. Finally, a *shape* parameter changes the shape of the distribution. For example, the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) has a shape parameter `k` that determines how skewed the distribution is (= how much it "leans" to one side).

> **But what does the `a` and `k` refer to?**

`k` is the variable parameterized by the distribution. With `zipf.pmf` you can compute the probability of any `k`, given shape parameter `a`. Below is a plot that demonstrates how `a`changes the shape of the distribution (the individual probabilities of different k).

[image]

A high `a` makes large values of `k` very unlikely, while a low `a` makes small `k` less likely and larger `k`are possible.

> **What does the `alpha` parameter mean?** Is that the "confidence interval"?

It is wrong to say that `alpha` *is* the confidence interval. It is the *confidence level*. I guess that is what you meant. For example, `alpha=0.95` Means that you have a 95% confidence interval. If you generate random `k`s from the particular distribution, 95% of them will be in the range returned by `zipf.interval`.

**Code for the plot:**

```
from scipy.stats import zipf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

k = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

for a in [1.3, 2.6]:
    p = zipf.pmf(k, a=a)

    plt.plot(k, p, label='a={}'.format(a), linewidth=2)

plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('probability')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```